# Paul's knowledge of Jannes and Jambres the magicians of Egypt

Tags: paul-apostle, moses, textual-criticism

Per Paul in:

**2 Timothy 3:8 ESV**

> Just as Jannes and Jambres opposed Moses, so these men also oppose the
>   truth, men corrupted in mind and disqualified regarding the faith.

Which is cross referenced to:

**Exodus 7:11 ESV**

> Then Pharaoh summoned the wise men and the sorcerers, and they, the
>   magicians of Egypt, also did the same by their secret arts.

and also

**Acts 13:8 ESV**

> But Elymas the magician (for that is the meaning of his name) opposed
>   them, seeking to turn the proconsul away from the faith.

**Titus 1:16**

> They profess to know God, but they deny him by their works. They are
>   detestable, disobedient, unfit for any good work.

How did Paul know the names of the Magicians since they appear to not be mentioned anywhere else in the bible by name?  And how was this cross reference made (how do we really know that he's talking about the same story)?

The only link that I can find is from the [Damascus Document](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0011_0_09984.html) which I was led to from reading [Moses in Biblical and Extra-Biblical Traditions](http://books.google.com/books?id=-J6Xn3iGwSAC&dq=annes%20and%20Jambres&source=gbs_navlinks_s) by Axel Graupner, Michael Wolter.

I'm going to ask this over at Hermeneutics too.  However I feel that this is an interesting doctoral question too.

Comment: There is discussion of this passage in [a Q&A on Heremeneutics.SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2871/2215).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's  in the Babylonian Talmud.

Torah comprises the Pentateuch in the main, but also the rest of the OT, as well as the commentaries, ie Talmud.

See also:

[Who were Jannes and Jambres?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/495/who-were-jannes-and-jambres)